# How to Populate a GridView with Drawables One Cell at a time

Tags: android, image, gridview, adapter, baseadapter

I was wondering if anyone had any idea of how to go about setting up an adapter to populate a GridView One cell at a time. I've managed to create a custom adapter that will populate every cell, but I want to do it one cell at a time based upon a click. In other words, you click a button, a image populates the first cell in the grid view. You press the button again, a image populates the second cell in the Grid View and So on. My Adapter code is shown below.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context myContext;


    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        myContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    //Create a new ImageView for each Item referenced by the adapter

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView image;
        if (convertView == null) {
            //If Image is not Recycled, set these attributes
            image = new ImageView(myContext);
            image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            image.setPadding(4,4,4,4);
        } else {
            image = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        image.setImageResource(imageId);
        return image;
    }


    //Reference to The Images
    private Integer imageId =
            R.drawable.red_ball;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter and initialize it to zero.

In your adapter, if the position is smaller than the counter, call image.setImageResource(imageId) otherwise call image.setImageDrawable(null).

When you press the button, increment the counter and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged().